# Using custom class in queryForList()

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am trying to use a custom class in **JDBCTemplate.queryForList** method as element type, but neither any data nor any error is being returned.

The custom class code is :

```
public class DocumentCategory {
        private int categoryId;
        private String description;
        private int divnId;
        private int depttId;
        private String revCategory;
        private boolean withBids;
        private boolean withFinalDocuments;
        private boolean editable;
        private int templateId;
        private String templateName;
        private boolean changed;
        private String remarks;
        private boolean withBidsChanged;
        private boolean withFinalDocumentsChanged;
        private int sortOrder;

        private String vdrNumber;

        public int getCategoryId() {
            return categoryId;
        }
        public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
            this.categoryId = categoryId;
        }
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
        public int getDivnId() {
            return divnId;
        }
        public void setDivnId(int divnId) {
            this.divnId = divnId;
        }
        public int getDepttId() {
            return depttId;
        }
        public void setDepttId(int depttId) {
            this.depttId = depttId;
        }
        public String getRevCategory() {
            return revCategory;
        }
        public void setRevCategory(String revCategory) {
            this.revCategory = revCategory;
        }
        public boolean isEditable() {
            return editable;
        }
        public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
            this.editable = editable;
        }
        public int getTemplateId() {
            return templateId;
        }
        public void setTemplateId(int templateId) {
            this.templateId = templateId;
        }
        public String getTemplateName() {
            return templateName;
        }
        public void setTemplateName(String templateName) {
            this.templateName = templateName;
        }
        public boolean isChanged() {
            return changed;
        }
        public void setChanged(boolean changed) {
            this.changed = changed;
        }
        public String getRemarks() {
            return remarks;
        }
        public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
            this.remarks = remarks;
        }
        public boolean getWithFinalDocuments() {
            return withFinalDocuments;
        }
        public void setWithFinalDocuments(boolean withFinalDocuments) {
            this.withFinalDocuments = withFinalDocuments;
        }
        public boolean getWithBids() {
            return withBids;
        }
        public void setWithBids(boolean withBids) {
            this.withBids = withBids;
        }
        public boolean isWithBidsChanged() {
            return withBidsChanged;
        }
        public void setWithBidsChanged(boolean withBidsChanged) {
            this.withBidsChanged = withBidsChanged;
        }
        public boolean isWithFinalDocumentsChanged() {
            return withFinalDocumentsChanged;
        }
        public void setWithFnalDocumentsChanged(boolean withFinalDocumentsChanged) {
            this.withFinalDocumentsChanged = withFinalDocumentsChanged;
        }
        public String getVdrNumber() {
            return vdrNumber;
        }
        public void setVdrNumber(String vdrNumber) {
            this.vdrNumber = vdrNumber;
        }
        public int getSortOrder() {
            return sortOrder;
        }
        public void setSortOrder(int sortOrder) {
            this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
        }

}
```

And the query code is :

```
sql = "SELECT -serialno as categoryId, describe as description,16 as divnId, 51 as depttId , NVL2( prnmatter, 'For Review', 'For Record') as revCategory, NVL2( prnquote, 1, 0) as withBids, NVL2( asbuild, 1, 0) as withFinalDocuments, VDRNO as vdrNumber, 0 as editable,100000 as templateId,'Instrumentation' as templateName, 0 as changed, '' as remarks, 0 as withBidsChanged, 0 as  withFinalDocumentsChanged, serialno as  sortOrder from Instreq.VDRData_to_DCTMVIEW WHERE REQNO=? AND PROJECTNO=? and predate= (SELECT * FROM(SELECT PREDATE FROM Instreq.VDRData_to_DCTMVIEW WHERE REQNO=? AND PROJECTNO=? ORDER BY PREDATE DESC) WHERE ROWNUM=1 )";
final List<DocumentCategory> dc = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, DocumentCategory.class, orderNumber, mrNumber, orderNumber, mrNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [query method taking a RowMapper as argument](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper%29), and transform each row returned in the result set into a DocumentCategory thanks to the RowMapper.

`queryForList()` is useful when the query returns a single column, to get back a `List<Integer>` or a `List<String>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of objects of your class type by:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<DocumentCategory>(DocumentCategory.class));
```